# How can I access the value of the target of a Func<Client, bool>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have C# a method that is declared as the following:

```
public IEnumerable<ClientEntity> Search(Func<Client, bool> searchPredicate)
{
    // Uses the search searchPredicate to perform a search.
}
```

This method gets called with something like:

```
string searchCriteria = "My Search Criteria";
bool searchOnlyActive = false;
myClientService.Search(c => c.Name.Contains(searchCriteria) && (c.Active || !searchOnlyActive));
```

Now, if I throw a breakpoint at the beginning of that method and I look at the searchPredicate properties in the Immediate Window, when I type searchPredicate.Target, I get something like this:

```
{MyNamespace.ClientsService.}
    searchCriteria: "My Search Criteria"
    searchOnlyActive: false
```

What I would like is to actually get the "My Search Criteria" value and the false value displayed there, like the debugger does, but I didn't manage to as the type of the Target property is something like "<>c__DisplayClass2" which I have no idea where that came from. I know it can be done because the debugger does it, I just don't know how.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You are properly returning an anonumous class (`<>c__DisplayClass2`) instead of you `ClientEntity`. Try showing the code that preforms the search

Comment: "get the values displayed there" => where? You already get them in the immediate window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<>c__DisplayClass2` is the class that the compiler invented to get the capture context. You can just use reflection:

```
object target = searchPredicate.Target;
if(target != null) {
    foreach(var field in target.GetType().GetFields()) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(target));
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
searchCriteria=My Search Criteria
searchOnlyActive=False
```

However! Unless you understand anonymous methods and captured variables (and how that is implemented in terms of compiler-generated context classes), I don't think this will do what you want it to; for example, there could be no context (a `Target` that is `null`), or multiple nested contexts...

Also: expression trees via `Expression<Func<Client,bool>>` are far more inspectable, if that is your intent.

Comment: I am not too worried about the context, I am only using this reflection to mock a couple of behaviours for unit testing so it will be a very controlled environment. Thanks again!